# Can't start Espresso test with mockwebserver: Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp

Tags: android, android-espresso, mockwebserver

Android Studio 3.3

in build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.KOTLIN_VERSION = '1.3.21'
    ext.ESPRESSO_VERSION = '3.2.0-alpha02'

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$KOTLIN_VERSION"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

In my app/build.gradle:

```
android {
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myproject.android"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 6
        versionName "0.0.8"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
        androidTest.java.srcDirs += 'src/androidTest/kotlin'
        //androidTest.assets.srcDirs += 'src/androidTest/assets'
    }

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.7.0@aar') { transitive = true; }

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.chauthai.swipereveallayout:swipe-reveal-layout:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.yuyh.json:jsonviewer:1.0.6'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$KOTLIN_VERSION"

    implementation project(':common')

    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$ESPRESSO_VERSION"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$ESPRESSO_VERSION"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$ESPRESSO_VERSION"
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.2-alpha02'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.2-alpha02'
    androidTestImplementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.14.1"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Here Espresso's test:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class TradersActivityTest {
     val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getContext()
    val targetContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext()
    var listItemCount = 0
    var checkItemCount = 0;
    val mockServer = MockWebServer()

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    var tradersIntentTestRule = IntentsTestRule(TradersActivity::class.java)

    @Before
    fun setup() {
        mockServer.start()
        val recyclerView = tradersIntentTestRule.activity.findViewById<View>(R.id.tradersRecyclerView) as RecyclerView
        listItemCount = recyclerView.adapter!!.itemCount
        checkItemCount = (0..listItemCount - 1).random()
    }
```

But I get error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugAndroidTestRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:{strictly 3.12.0}.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > Cannot find a version of 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp' that satisfies the version constraints: 
           Dependency path 'TM:app:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.14.1' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.1'
           Constraint path 'TM:app:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:{strictly 3.12.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 3.12.0
           Constraint path 'TM:app:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:{strictly 3.12.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 3.12.0
           Constraint path 'TM:app:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:{strictly 3.12.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 3.12.0
           Constraint path 'TM:app:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:{strictly 3.12.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 3.12.0
           Constraint path 'TM:app:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:{strictly 3.12.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 3.12.0
           Constraint path 'TM:app:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:{strictly 3.12.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 3.12.0
           Constraint path 'TM:app:unspecified' --> 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:{strictly 3.12.0}' because of the following reason: debugRuntimeClasspath uses version 3.12.0
```

Answer (score 4):

This is happening because you are not specifying a specific OkHttp dependency in your app. When you don't specify one yourself then gradle will use the default version specified by Retrofit. If you check [Retrofit POM file](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/81a6193a7b3f2b1bf25e78adc2638681b0514fe8/pom.xml#L53) you can see that it specifies `3.12.0` which is where this version you are seeing in the error is coming from.

The solution is to add a specific gradle dependency for the version of OkHttp that you want to use:

`implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.1'`

This version would then be used instead of the default retrofit one and matches the requirement for your mock server version

Comment: Now another error: Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform artifact 'okhttp.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.1)' to match attributes {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-is-debuggable=true, dexing-min-sdk=18, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime-jars}
      > Execution failed for DexingTransform: C:\Users\Alexei\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\f941c32b9727fea784aedf1d9d9f5a1f\jetified-okhttp-3.14.1.jar.
         > Error while dexing.